# macOS - Finder Sync and Device Backup?

Tags: macos, finder, backup

on: BigSur 11.6

Does anyone know if the finder sync only syncs the data and doesn't do a backup of the device?

-- reason why I ask. When I plug in my device the sync initiates but the backup doesn't I can confirm this by seeing the last sync date.

-- I know in iTunes the backup would occur every 24hrs through local or wifi.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136

1. states "A computer backup of your device, which is not the same as a sync, includes almost all of your device's data and settings."

Comment: If you have turned iCloud Backup on, on the device, the mac will never back it up locally unless you explicitly initiate one.  This is by design.

Comment: Thanks for the Response.  I'm not using or will be using iCloud Backup.  Actually it was in Catalina not in Big Sur.